# Tex editor online

Tags: editors

Sometimes One does not wish to post a problem/solution directly as a ques/ans at stackexchange sites, but posts indirectly (share the link, and that link contains the ques/ans in math(latex ) format). what are those latex writing and sharing pad?

Comment: If someone only shares the link pointing to the document they have, they will be asked to add the code (and?) a screenshot. I'm sure no more than 5-10 users will click on that link.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Don't use Pastebin or Overleaf or anything here unless the code is thousands line long.